# CMS for allowing users to delete or edit a post

Tags: php

I have been working on a personal CMS for a site I've been running, and right now I'm working on a page that lists all entries, or posts from a database. I have given the user, with checkboxes and a drop down menu, the option to either delete or edit a post.

```
    //query database
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userPosts");

    //turn query results into an array
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) :

    //List all posts in a table (other table markup not shown).
    $posts = $rows['userTexts'];
    $id = $rows['ID'];
    echo "<tr>\n<td>" . $id . "</td>\n<td class='posts'>" . $posts . "</td>\n<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkBox' value='chk[". $id . "]'></td>\n</tr>\n";
endwhile
```

This part is not the problem, but I figure it is necessary for the question. Is there a way to make this code cleaner, without so many `if` statements?

```
$chkWhat = $_REQUEST["chkBox"];
$options = $_REQUEST["options"];


if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {
    if($chkWhat != "chk[" .$id . "]") {
        echo "<p>Please select a post.</p>";
    } else {
        if( //more than one check box is checked but I still have to figure this...) {
            echo "<p>For now, please just select 1 post you would like to edit.</p>";
        } else {
            //edit your post
            echo "You will edit your post";
        }
        if($options == "delete") {
            //delete your post(s) here
            echo "You will delete your post(s)";
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about the second `if` statement there, but I am still researching that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can use switch statements to clean up abundant if statements, but only if those if statements are similar; Such as checking for different values of the same variable. Since that is not the case here, there isn't much you can change in this area. Sometimes you just need a few if statements. I would, however, suggest that you not use the global `$_REQUEST` as it is rather insecure. Even if you think you are the only one who is ever going to use it, what if someone got in, you just removed one more step of security from your site making it that much more easier for someone to destroy your hard work. Even you could make a mistake later by accidentally duplicating a POST variable as a GET variable, or vice-versa. Or someone with malicious intent does it on purpose, you could run into a lot of problems there. You should also sanitize those. Check out [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) (>=PHP 5.2) to get started, or check other forums on the best way to sanitize your form variables.

Your delima with checking for multiple checkboxes should be rather easy. You've already got your form set up to make them into an array after post. Or almost right. You need to change name to what you have for your value. That should work, but if it doesn't try making the value the `$id` and just leaving the name `chk[]`, should probably do that anyways as it won't leave empty or useless values. After that just check the count.

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['chk[]'];
if(count($checkboxes) > 1) { etc... }
```

There is a minor change you should make to your if statements. Since you are checking `$options` for a "delete" value, you should also check it for an "edit" value, or move that if statement into the else block and give it an else for the edit block. Otherwise, as you can imagine, you'll end up editing and then deleting your posts and that would take up unneeded resources.

```
if( //more than one check box is checked but I still have to figure this...) {
    echo "<p>For now, please just select 1 post you would like to edit.</p>";
} else {
    if($options == "delete") { /*delete your post*/ }
    else { /*edit your post*/ }
}
```

I don't see anything else really. So good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into OOP for your PHP and (optionally) ORM instead of your standard DB queries.

It's much cleaner and easier to work with then procedures. What you have now - a huge long file (ok, bunch of files) with the wall of PHP code.

What you will achieve using OOP: Separated **blocks** of code. It's much easier to get back to this. More - instead of mess in your huge file you will have neat method calls like: `$user->login($username, $password)`

Comment: Interesting... any ideas where to start learning about "OOP for my PHP"?

Comment: @St8upNewb Just google 'object oriented php tutroial' - you'll find something that will suit you. One more thing - when you'll start feeling pretty comfortable with OOP - try reading about MVC and designing your next application keeping MVC structure in mind.

Comment: OOP is a good suggestion, but MVC, while popular, is still a preference. Still both good suggestions for a larger program. If there isn't much more to this code though, it will be rather redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few comments that I can't find in the other answers.

- mysql_* is softly deprecated (use PDO or mysqli)
- while : endwhile is an uncommon choice compared to using braces { }. Consider using braces as they look nicer mixed in with if statements and other block elements that share braces IMO.
- Indent the contents of your while loop as you do with your if statements.

Comment: yes, I actually meant to mention those first two, but the second is common enough if being used in a view file. Although the rest of the code does tend to lean more away from that. I completely missed the third +1

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could be condensed a little, but overall, it's solid code. Consider using a ternary operator for your conditional echos:

```
echo count($_REQUEST['chkBox']) > 1 ? "<p>For now, please just select 1 post you would like to edit.</p>" : "You will edit your post";
```

Comment: consider to move all your echoes to *template*

Comment: Ternary operations should be short a sweet. If you were to do this, you'd be almost REQUIRED to move those strings to variables before processing them. Better to just set a default output string then if a certain condition is met change that string to the new output.

Answer (score 0):

**Reducing indentation.** If, in a function, there are multiple levels of indentation, these can be reduced with 'guard clauses' - http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses

For the top-level it could be removed by converting the first `if()` to:

```
   if (! isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {
       return;
   }
   // rest of code here, at the same indentation level.
```

Putting that block (the outside `if()`) into a function, allows a simple exit of the block with a return out of the function.

Equally, with a function, you could pass in the `$_REQUEST["submit"]`, `$chkWhat`, and `$id` variables, to give just a small measure of potential clarification as to what they are, without using the super-global too widely.

Answer (score -1):

Both question and answer lacks common sense.
So here I am! :)

1. You cannot reduce number of conditions, *as long as these conditions make sense.*
2. Of course OOP won't reduce it either. It will just move them much deeper in the code (and dramatically increase the code amount [you will have to debug if something goes wrong]).
3. There is no reason to make some of the conditions nested.
4. Most wondering part. **Why do you use checkboxes if only one post can be edited at once?** Just for sake of using it with delete button? I am wondering if you ever been using some web interfaces. The controls to operate some posts are commonplace, there are some general ways - why not to follow them?

To edit posts it is common to make *a hyperlink* on the post name. A hyperlink will lead to the edit script, not to the POST processing script. But only after hitting "save" button the edit process will proceed to POST processing code.

While mass delete will go directly to the POST processing, but you will need as small code as

```
$err = '';
if(!$_POST["chkBox"]) {
    $err .= "No posts selected";
}
if (!$err) {
   //delete
   // Location header with redirect
   //exit
} else {
  // fill dorm data variables
}
// show the form
```

Comment: @Your Common Sense. To link the post name to the edit script would make sense...!

But um _"I am wondering if you ever been using some web interfaces"_...? Explain, please?